# Bespoke pricing chart and table for Wordpress/Elementor

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

I want to create a table for my Elementor front end which has 5 interactive fields/dropdowns (blue text below) which refers to source data in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MvkokTRGJKAMCVzMuPO0QQfxY8B2luVnL_Hf_Lxmawo/edit?usp=sharing) and displays a graph in Elementor like the ones pictured below. I've explored wpdatatables, Visualizer and a few other plugins but it doesn't look like they will achieve this.

Any advice how to even start going about achieving this?

[image]

**After tweaking the blue text boxes/dropdowns...**

[image]